# Mysql return enumeration of numbers in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return the numbers 1,2,3,4 from mysql in *different* rows.

If I run

`select 1,2,3,4` then I will get *a single row* with these four numbers.

How can I get four different rows each with a single number ?

Please don't answer me to create a table containing these numbers ! Also the use case is for a jasper report I want to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) to concat the rows:

```
SELECT 1 AS ColumnName
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS ColumnName
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS ColumnName
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4 AS ColumnName
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/28573/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ! I accepted @Tim's answetr because I think he was the 1st one to answer...

Answer (score 3):

Try using UNION

```
select 1 as col_name
UNION
select 2
UNION
select 3
UNION
select 4
```

If some of your values occur more than once (say you have two 1s and you want them both in your returned rows), then you may want to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

e.g

```
select 1 from  ..
union  
select 2 from  ..
union  
select 3 from ..
union  
select 4 from ..
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using UNION:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM   tablename 
UNION 
SELECT 2 
FROM   tablename 
UNION 
SELECT 3 
FROM   tablename 
UNION 
SELECT 4 
FROM   tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4;
```

The result

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
+---+
```